# VBA to select two files, perform vlookup across the workbooks, then save results in new file

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm still new to VBA so I hope this question is specific enough. Every day I work with two files that require the same operation of performing a vlookup, filtering down the N/As and copying and pasting into a new file. So I want to make a macro that will automate this as much as possible.  BUT... here's the kicker, the original files change every day. So here's where I need help... I'm okay with after I run the macro, manually selecting the two files I want the macro to work with but how do I do this? If someone can help me with this portion, I can add the proper formatting and vlookup functions to the code.

thank you all and if you have any questions please feel free to comment. The code I have so far is written below... I know its pretty messy sorry.

thanks again.

Sub reserve_secondary_test()

```
Windows("PAERR20180319.CSV").Activate
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim finalrow As Long
Set sht = ActiveSheet
finalrow = sht.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'concatenate new file
range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
[A1].FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[2],RC[3])"
range("A1").Copy Destination:=sht.range("A1", sht.range("A" & finalrow))

'concatenate og file
Windows("r319og.csv").Activate
'Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim endrow As Long
Set sht = ActiveSheet
endrow = sht.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
[A1].FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[2],RC[3])"
range("A1").Copy Destination:=sht.range("A1", sht.range("A" & endrow))

'vlookup og file (reference new file)
[B1].FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],PAERR20180319.CSV!R1:R1048576,1,FALSE)"
range("B1").Copy Destination:=sht.range("B1", sht.range("B" & endrow))

'filter for N/As
[B1].AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="#N/A"
[A1].CurrentRegion.Copy

'paste into new file
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim shtt As Worksheet
Set shtt = ActiveSheet
lastrow = shtt.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    If Cells(1, 2).Value <> "#N/A" Then
    Cells(1, 2).EntireRow.Delete

'formatting for import
[A1].EntireColumn.Delete
[A1].FormulaR1C1 = "   "
range("A1").Copy Destination:=shtt.range("A1", shtt.range("A" & lastrow))
shtt.range("C1", shtt.range("C" & lastrow)).NumberFormat = "00000000"
shtt.range("D1", shtt.range("D" & lastrow)).NumberFormat = "000"
shtt.range("E1", shtt.range("E" & lastrow)).NumberFormat = "00000000"
shtt.range("F1", shtt.range("F" & lastrow)).NumberFormat = "000000000"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Z:\TodayNA.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, 
CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close [savechanges]
```

End Sub

Comment: Adding the code will certainly help! As it stands, you're asking any random person on the internet to write a module for you without knowing anything about your environment. The chances of that happening are potentially less than 0. Someone simply correcting a mistake in your code is far more likely.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I have added the code I have so far. Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe further explain what exactly you want to do? You have a data table and want to copy certain values into another table? And deleting #N/A 's?

Comment: Sure, So I'm working with two files. The original file gets uploaded into a program which spits back a second file. This program removes some rows for import and then returns an error file with the remaining rows from the original. I need to figure out which rows it removed so I concatenate a few columns and perform a vlookup. When I filter to only show the N/As these are the rows that were removed. I copy and paste these N/As into a new document and upload the file a second time. If I did the operation correctly It will return a confirmation screen. Does this help Peter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you need to add some code to automatically open the files and insert your code in between it. Below you'll find an example. I'm assuming the files you want to open are the only csv files in the folder. If that's not the case, the code will have to be edited.

```
Sub OpenFiles()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

MyFolder = "include your path here"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.csv")

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile

    '----- insert the rest of your code here -------

    '-----------------------------------------------

    MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! There are a bunch of old .CSV files in my folder. is there a way to manually select the two files I am currently working with?

Comment: To open use: `Workbooks.Open ("INSERT FILE LOCATION HERE/FileName.csv")` and to select use `Workbooks("FileName.csv").Activate`
 @Mnathan

Comment: Is it possible to identify the filename somehow? We could use an if statement. From what you've said, I'm not sure the filename is always the same.

Comment: Is there an object/variable that I can use to find the file that ends with "new"? Then I can manually change the file name to end with new before I run the macro to ensure it's pulling the correct file. Sorry if this is confusing but I appreciate all your help!

Comment: If you substitute MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.csv") for MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*new.csv"), it should do the trick. But it would probably be better if we could find another solution. Maybe you could store filenames on a spreadsheet and only open the ones that don't belong to that list. Whenever you run the macro, it adds the newly added files to the folder of csv that shouldn't be opened. But maybe thats too complicated for now. See if the "*new.csv" works and we can see where to go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help Bezurli! I added my up to date code for this macro (it looks a lot cleaner but still not perfect). At this point I run into two problems.

Comment: 1) I need a way for the code to look in my Z drive for two specified file names and open them. and 2) my If statement works correctly if something other than #N/A is listed but if #N/A is listed I get a mismatch error. I just want it to ignore it if #N/A is listed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I still haven't understood how you want to open the files. Do you know the file path and the file name? Or do you to find it out somehow? For the #N/A, try: If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(1, 2).Value) Then
    Cells(1, 2).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: Yes. The file path is "Z:\". The first file is named "OriginalReserve" (replacing r319og) and the second is "NewReserve" (replacing the PAERR file). And for the N/As... If cell B1 does NOT contain #N/A then I want to delete the entire row. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @bezurli I got the files to open correctly but am still having trouble with my IF function. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Try inserting a not statement after the if. If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(1, 2).Value) Then Cells(1, 2).EntireRow.Delete